# Vagrant-aws not provisioning

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, puppet, vagrant

I'm trying to spin up and provision an EC2 instance with Vagrant, it successfully creates the instance up and I can then use `vagrant ssh`  to SSH into the it but Puppet doesn't seem to carry out any provisioning.

Upon running `vagrant up --provider=aws --provision` I get the following output

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...

WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1
[default] Warning! The AWS provider doesn't support any of the Vagrant
high-level network configurations (`config.vm.network`). They
will be silently ignored.

[default] Launching an instance with the following settings...
[default]  -- Type: m1.small
[default]  -- AMI: ami-a73264ce
[default]  -- Region: us-east-1
[default]  -- Keypair: banderton
[default]  -- Block Device Mapping: []
[default]  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false

[default] Waiting for SSH to become available...
[default] Machine is booted and ready for use!
[default] Rsyncing folder: /Users/benanderton/development/projects/my-project/aws/ => /vagrant
[default] Rsyncing folder: /Users/benanderton/development/projects/my-project/aws/manifests/ => /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] Rsyncing folder: /Users/benanderton/development/projects/my-project/aws/modules/ => /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
[default] Running provisioner: puppet...
An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
Any errors that occurred are shown below.

An error occurred while executing the action on the 'default'
machine. Please handle this error then try again:

No error message
```

I can then SSH into the instance by using `vagrant ssh` but none of my provisioning has taken place, so I'm assuming that errors have occured but I'm not being given any useful information relating to them.

My Vagrantfile is as following;

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu_aws"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "REDACTED"
    aws.secret_access_key = "REDACTED"
    aws.keypair_name = "banderton"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/banderton.pem"
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    aws.ami = "ami-a73264ce"
  end

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
    puppet.options = ['--verbose']
  end  
end
```

My Puppet manifest is as following;

```
package { [
    'build-essential',
    'vim',
    'curl',
    'git-core',
    'nano',
    'freetds-bin'
  ]:
  ensure  => 'installed',
}
```

None of the packages are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "No error message" issue should have been fixed in Vagrant 1.3.5. But you should be able to see the actual error by enabling more logging:

```
VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up --provider=aws --provision
```

For even mode debug log, use `VAGRANT_LOG=debug`.